Intersect tool in QGIS produces an empty layer
I am trying to follow the QGIS tutorial in https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/analysis_combination.html section 8.2.1. I am working with the exercise data provided, and have all the required layers set up:

I'm trying to use the intersect tool with this setup (syötetaso = input ; peitetaso = overlay):

The log shows this output:
Ladataan tulostasoja
Algoritmi 'Ristiinleikkaus (intersection)' päättyi
QGIS-versio: 3.36.3-Maidenhead
QGIS-koodin versio: 2df96554
Qt-versio: 5.15.13
Python-versio: 3.12.3
GDAL-versio: 3.9.0
GEOS-versio: 3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1
PROJ-versio: Rel. 9.4.0, March 1st, 2024
PDAL-versio: 2.6.3 (git-version: b5523a)
Algoritmin suoritus alkoi: 2024-08-01T17:16:21
Algoritmi Ristiinleikkaus (intersection) käynnistyy…
Syöttöparametrit:
{ 'GRID_SIZE' : None, 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/xxxxx/Documents/QGIS/QGIS-Training-Data-master/exercise_data/vector_analysis.gpkg|layername=solution', 'INPUT_FIELDS' : [], 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'OVERLAY' : 'C:/Users/xxxxx/Documents/QGIS/QGIS-Training-Data-master/exercise_data/residential_development/suitable_terrain.shp', 'OVERLAY_FIELDS' : [], 'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX' : '' }

Creating spatial index
Calculating intersection
Execution completed in 0.57 sekuntia
Tulokset:
  OUTPUT: Ristiinleikkaus__intersection__01a15708_d221_4ede_96a7_5e0f5ea7abe9

Ladataan tulostasoja
Algoritmi 'Ristiinleikkaus (intersection)' päättyi

However, when I go to the attribute table of the new layer this produces, it is completely blank:

What am I missing here? It should just produce a new layer with the buildings from "solution" that intersect with "suitable_terrain", but why is that not happening?

The CRS are different for both layers, one in 32734 and the other one in 32733. You need to project one of them to be similar to the other before doing intersection.

I reprojected suitable_terrain to 32734, but I'm still getting the same blank attribute table.

After reprojection, open a new QGIS project, add the layers after reprojections, and try the intersection again.

Try Fix geometries on both input layers then try Intersecting the fixed layers

ahmadhanb, adding the layers to a new project fixed the issue! I have no idea what was wrong, but everything worked exactly as it should. Thank you!

The CRS are different for both layers, one in EPSG:32734 and the other in EPSG:32733. Before doing an intersection, you need to project one of them to match the projection of the other layer.
If the problem persists, open a new QGIS project, add the layers after reprojections, and try the intersection again.
